# How to write a function that recognises unbalanced brackets

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to write a function that checks if a syntax is correct or not. If it is correct it returns 'ok' else it returns the index of the error. So far my code works if it is correct, if the error is at the first index or last index. Finding errors inbetween is what i am finding difficult. Here is my code.

```
function syntaxError(syntax) {

  let arr = syntax.split('').join()
  let arr1 = [];
  let arr2 = [];
  let result;

  //Error if the first index contain a closing braces

  if (arr[0] === '>' || arr[0] === ']' || arr[0] === '}' || arr[0] === ')') {
    result = 0
  };

  if (arr === "") {
    result = 'ok'
  };

  //Error if its just a single brace

  if (arr.length === 1) {
    result = 0
  };

  //Error if the last index contain an opening braces

  if (arr.slice(-1) === '<' || arr.slice(-1) === '[' || arr.slice(-1) === '{' || arr.slice(-1) === '(') {
    result = indexOf(arr.slice(-1))
  };

  let char = arr[i];

  if (char == '[' || char == '{' || char == '<' || char == '(') {
    arr1.push(char)
  } else {
    arr2.push(char);
  }

  if (arr1.length === 0 || arr2.length === 0) {
    result = 0
  }

  if (arr1.length === arr2.length) {
    result = 'ok'

  }

  return result
}
```

The example below should return 95

```
('[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>]]]]]]'+'[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]

<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>]}]]]]' + '>')
```

Comment: you mean, your function should check for balanced brackets?

Comment: yes, and it should return the index position of the error if there is any.

Comment: you should use some kind of an data structure like stack.https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-data-structure/ In fact, you can use usual **array** like a stack. The problem is known as **balanced parentheses problem** https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/ returning an index might require to add a bit more to the existing solution in the last link

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix console errors

Comment: also, what is a position of an error exactly, for example in `[ [ [ ] ]` should it be 0 or 5?

Comment: What about situations like this, `(({)})`? Are you going to check for that?

Comment: should be 2, cos the third opening braces will not have a closing braces

Comment: But the inner most braces are closed, it should return an index of 5 because it should expect a closing brace there.

Comment: ( ( { ) } ) should return 1, cos the second closing bracket is inbetween the complete curly braces

Comment: But the error is at index 3, a closing curly brace should be expected there.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a an array for the index of each opening character and pop this if the related closing character is found.

If finished and the stack has no item, the syntax is ok, otherwise return an index or the index of the last pushed opening character.

> Example:
>
> ```
> code        comment
> ----------- ---------------------------
> [][[[]][][]
> []          balanced
>   [         error, this returns later 2
>    [[]]     balanced
>        []   balanced
>          [] balanced
>             finally a missing ]
> ```

```js
function syntaxError(syntax) {
    const
        isOpening = c => /[<[{(]/.test(c),
        isClosing = c => /[>\]})]/.test(c),
        open = { '>': '<', ']': '[', '}': '{', ')': '(' };

    var stack = [],
        index,
        finished = Array
            .from(syntax)
            .every((c, i) => {
                var temp = stack[stack.length - 1];
                if (isOpening(c)) {
                    if (temp && temp.c === c) {
                        temp.indices.push(i);
                    } else {
                        stack.push({ c, indices: [i] });
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                if (isClosing(c)) {
                    if (temp && temp.c === open[c]) {
                        temp.indices.pop();
                        if (!temp.indices.length) stack.pop();
                    } else {
                       index = stack.length ? stack.pop().indices.pop() : i;
                       return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            });

    return finished && !stack.length
        ? 'ok'
        : index === undefined
            ? stack.pop().indices.pop()
            : index;
}

console.log(syntaxError('[][][[{}]]'));  // ok

console.log(syntaxError(')'));
//                       0

console.log(syntaxError('[][][[{<}]]'));
//                       01234567

console.log(syntaxError('[][[[]][][]'));
//                       012

console.log(syntaxError('[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>]]]]]]'+'[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>]}]]]]' + '>'));
```

Comment: Good answer, but Op has indicated that they want the index of the opening symbol that doesn't have a closing symbol. And that they consider that the innermost opening symbol needs to match the outer most closing one, for some reason. My algorithm doesn't address this behavior either.

Comment: the problem is, open brackets are always right, only if a missing closing bracket throws the errror.

Comment: I agree completely, but op has other ideas :)

Comment: BTW, I find it more practical to use un(shift) with stacks rather than push/pop so that you can use `stack[0]` and not the ugly `stack[stack.length - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm for doing this is, find an opening symbol, push it to a stack (or array, whatever). Find another opening symbol, push it to a stack. Find a closing symbol that matches the top of the stack, pop the opening symbol off the stack. Find a closing symbol that doesn't match the top of the stack, you found an error. Find a closing symbol and there's nothing on the stack, you found an error. Get to the end and still have symbols on the stack, you found an error.